# What are these connectors?

Tags: identification

Specifically, the plug and socket at each end.

This is a board-to-board cable from a 1989-era Toshiba laptop, which connects a dedicated modem port to the modem itself (not present in my laptop). The pinout is a very cut-down ISA bus with only a few address lines, and looks eminently suitable for hacking --- if I can find a plug which will go into the motherboard connector (I'd rather not destroy this one). But for that, I need to know what it is; the cable markings are no help. (I'm hoping to find an IDC variant.) What is it?

[image: mysteeerious connectors]

Comment: GPIB connectors were much larger than that.

Comment: Measure the pitch more accurately and see if you can find it on Digikey/Mouser.

Comment: Pin pitch is 0.8mm. The width of the central island is ~2mm. Mouser has about a billion different kinds of these, all very very slightly different. Incidentally, further inspection shows that that the brown end (which is either a socket or a plug) has 0179 written on it, and the black end (which is either a plug or a socket) has 0131 on it, so these are likely to be the model numbers from whoever the manufacturer is.

Comment: the closest I've found so far: https://www.hirose.com/product/download/?distributor=digikey&type=2d&lang=en&num=FX6A-30S-0.8SV2(93)

Comment: how tall are the two (between the PCBs) when mated?  "stacking height" is one of the parameters on this page:https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-arrays-edge-type-mezzanine-board-to-board/308?FV=1600014%2Cii2%7C2172%2Cffe00134%2C164006d&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&cad=0&datasheet=0&nstock=0&photo=0&nonrohs=0&newproducts=0&quantity=&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500

Comment: IDC could be tricky, you'd need 0.4mm pitch cable

Comment: Jasen seems to have found something from Hirose. If not, maybe check Samtec.

Comment: Can you confirm the pin pitch? Checking the pixels, and given the meter shown in the picture, I get something like 1.27, not 0.8. Also, the slot width seems narrower than 2mm. More like 1.6mm, which is consistent with a standard PCB thickness.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, however has anyone looked at 3M part [P50-030P-R1-EA](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/3m/P50-030P-R1-EA/P50-030P-R1-EA-ND/2340916)?

The pitch is not right but the angle mounts match this series.

[image] [image]

It's likely in the same 3M P50 family https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/3M-Pak-50-Boardmount-Plug-P50-Series/?N=5002385+3290316870&rt=rud or similar. A high probability that 3M makes it based on the similarities.

Comment: Or rephrased to illustrate that it's likely a 3m part in the same family. A link to the family guide would make it more of an answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here is a link to the P50 series.https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/3M-Pak-50-Boardmount-Plug-P50-Series/?N=5002385+3290316870&rt=rud

Answer (score -1):

I **think** they are 30pin SCSI connectors.  I have had a look around, and 30pin seems to be an odd size.

[Wikipedia image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_connector#/media/File:Scsi-connectors.jpg) - look at the bottom connector

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_connector)

Comment: Having worked with SCSI for decades, I know the connector in the question above is *not* a standard SCSI connector. It is *slightly* similar, but so are lots of connectors!

Comment: scale is wrong, shell shape is wrong, "centronics" same deal.